# redirect parent webpage from popup that loads a website that redirects?

Tags: html, redirect, inheritance, popup

Is there a way to have:

- open a popup from an existing page(main page)
- in this popup load a website that will redirect to some location, and make the ( main page ) load this redirected url and close the popup?

so:

- http://myapp.com/mypage.html => opens popup => this popup opens a page that redirects => instead of loading this redirect in the popup "pass" it to the parent window so that window reloads => then close the popup?

Comment: If everything's on the same domain, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can redirect main page from popup.

in popup page, you need to have a code like:

```
<script language=”javascript”>
top.location = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```